# nested operators

Tags: python, nested, tuples, operator-keyword

I'm trying to write a tuple list comprehension using operators in python 2.7, tkinter.  Alpha is the original data, beta the result.

```
alpha=[(A,1,1,2),
(B,2,2,2),
(C,3,1,2)]
```

product

```
beta=[(alpha[0],"%.2f"% reduce(mul,alpha[1:])) for alpha in alpha]
beta
[(A,2.00),(B,8.00),(C,6.00)]
```

sum

```
beta=[(alpha[0],"%.2f"% reduce(add,alpha[1:])) for alpha in alpha]
beta
[(A,4.00),(B,6.00),(C,6.00)]
```

But when I try to combine these for nested operations, I'm stumped.  How do I get the

sum of products?

```
beta
[(A,16.00),(B,16.00),(C,16.00)]
```

products / sum of products?

```
beta
[(A,0.13),(B,0.44),(C,0.38)]
```

I've tried various iterations of the following with no success

```
beta=[(alpha[0],"%.2f"% reduce(add, map(mul,alpha[1:])) for alpha in alpha]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
In [46]: alpha=[('A',1,1,2),('B',2,2,2),('C',3,1,2)]

In [49]: total = float(sum(reduce(mul,a[1:]) for a in alpha))

In [50]: total
Out[50]: 16.0

In [51]: [(a[0], "%.2f" % (reduce(mul,a[1:])/total)) for a in alpha]
Out[51]: [('A', '0.12'), ('B', '0.50'), ('C', '0.38')]
```

I assume the `0.44` is a typo. If it isn't, please clarify how it should be computed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use anonymous functions with reduce:

```
sum_of_products = [(x[0], float(reduce(lambda y,z: y+z*z, x[1:],0))) for x in alpha]
```